# Cryptographic range based random number generator class 2.0

Tags: c#, random

I've corrected the bug in the first version and fixed up the error messages.

As for using floating arithmetic, since i'm not using more than 10 digits of the generated double, which, to my understanding, has at least 14 significant digits I can't see how the rounding will effect the outcome.

As for the randomness of the results, I can't seem to find any bias in the results of this algorithm.  Perhaps someone has a better test and hard numbers, instead of blind theory.

```
        public static class CryptoRandom
        {
            const double MAX_RANGE = (double)UInt64.MaxValue + 1;

            /// <summary>
            /// Internal algorithm to generate the range based integers.           
            /// </summary>
            static int Next(UInt64 min, UInt64 max)
            {
                if (max < min)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"max is less than min.  The values are, min = {min}, max = {max}");
                }
                if(min < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"min is negative.  The value is min = {min}");
                }
                if (min == max)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"min equals max.  The values are, min = {min}, max = {max}");
                }

                using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    byte[] randomNumber = new byte[8];

                    rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                    double baseNum = BitConverter.ToUInt64(randomNumber, 0) / MAX_RANGE;

                    UInt64 range = max - min;

                    return (int)((baseNum * range) + min);
                }

            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Get a cryptographic random 32-bit integer in the range from
            /// min(inclusive) to max(exclusive)
            /// </summary>
            public static int Next(int min, int max)
            {
                return (int)Next((UInt64)min, (UInt64)max);
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Get a cryptographic random 32-bit integer in the range from
            /// 0 to max(exclusive)
            /// </summary>
            public static int Next(int max)
            {
                return (int)Next(0, (UInt64)max);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get a cryptographic random 32-bit integer
            /// </summary>
            public static int Next()
            {
                return (int)Next(0, (UInt64)Int32.MaxValue+1);
            }


        }
```

Comment: I can't comment on the statistics of it because i haven't checked the distribution of 100000s of the random numbers generated, but i can make some comments about the naming of the methods/class - which you may find useful: https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/9eb15c6cb42471f4a50f9d03029dd98b

Answer (score 3):

First of all somehing trivial:

- When `max < min` or `max == min` you correctly throw `ArgumentException` but then for `min < 0`you should throw `ArgumentOufOfRangeException` however...`ulong` cannot be less than zero then this check is meaningless.
- There is a needless cast in the other overloads of `Next()`: return value is already an `int`.
- If you cast `int` to `ulong` (signed to unsigned) you may want to do it in a `checked` environment to, at least, have a run-time error instead of wrong but undetected values (I assume that you do not want to penalize distribution simply discarding ms bits).
- You may replace `new byte[8]` with `new byte[sizeof(ulong)]`.

Now more serious things...

Using `double` for such big range you effectively break the distribution of your random numbers (because above a threshold even integer numbers cannot be represented correctly in floating point). I understand that you're doing that to keep an apparent upper limit equal to `UInt64.MaxValue` but you're sacrificing randomness. It may be an issue or not, in your case, but be aware of it.

As you already know `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` generates random bytes and `Convert.ToUInt64()` is not enough to have a *true* randomly generated number (because each byte, not their *composition*, is supposed to be randomly distributed). There is a technique you're somehow applying to compensate this issue and it's described by Stephen Toub and Shawn Farkas in [Tales from the CryptoRandom](https://web.archive.org/web/20090304194122/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc163367.aspx). I suggest to pick their code and to use it as-is until you completely understand their implementation (and the implication of any change). Not that this will  introduce any big bias in your calculations but unless you statistically validate your algorithm I think you should stick to well-known and reviewed implementations.

As Adam already noted in his answer you should not have a static class and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` should be a class member. Let the caller decide how your random number generator should be used to have a better distribution. Don't forget to implement `IDisposable` also for your class. Also consider to accept ctor parameter of type `RandomNumberGenerator` (which can be mocked in your tests), you may want to *test* your code with a well-known set of inputs, not with random ones:

```
public sealed class CryptoRandom : IDisposable
{
    public CryptoRandom(RandomNumberGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(generator));
    }

    public CryptoRandom()
        : this(new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
    }

    // ...

    private readonly RandomNumberGenerator _generator;
}
```

There is, finally, an even more serious problem. If you initialize `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` without a seed then it will use `Environment.TickCount` and its **resolution is limited to the system timer resolution** (typically 10 ms), this alone will practically vanish most of your effort.

Comment: I'm not at all sure you're right about the range of the double being an issue. A double has 53 bits of precision, which means that choosing a 32-bit integer this way will result in less than 1/2^-21 bias for any given integer. You couldn't even write a program that could even detect such a small bias, even running 24/7/365 on a supercomputer.

Comment: Also, I think your assertion about the distribution of bits in RNGCryptoServiceProvider is wrong. It would be a very dangerous thing if there was any correlation between the bits produced by it, in fact the whole point of a *crypto* service provider is to make absolutely, 100%, sure that there isn't a correlation between any of the successive bits, of any sort. Unlike floating point numbers, where if you choose random bits you don't get a uniform distribution, @tinstaafl is converting to a UInt64, which is fine.

Comment: @Adam Range of double **is** an issue. You do not need to run 24/7 to find that number. Just declare a `double` variable `x` and set it to `9007199254740991`, now compare the result of `x + 1` and `x + 2` and you'll (surprising?) see that they're the same. Note that this number is well below `ulong.MaxValue`. That's the maximum integer number you can represent with a double precision floating number without losing any precision.

Comment: About second assertion: that's EXACTLY the problem. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is a cryptographic number generator then it's _good_. Generated values have a good distribution. However combining 8 bytes to form a value with a bigger range is not the same as generating a value with that range. It's not formally correct (no need to explain why) but think about this intuitive example: three `ulong` values 1, 2 and 3 have a good distribution. However to generate those values from 24 `byte` (3 * 8) you need these values: 1, 2, 3 and...21 times 0. Thats's a bad distribution.

Comment: wrong on both points, I think. Firstly, 2^53 is the largest integer that double can represent exactly, yes. But he is mashing them back down into the integer range with a floating point divide. So each possible integer value in the output is going to map to 2^21 random double values. Not a problem if for some integers that is 2^21 + 1 and for others just 2^21.

Comment: On the second point, if you chose the bits of an integer randomly, the integer is going to be uniform in the range of it's representation. Trivially true. Let's say I choose only the MSB randomly. Half of the time, the number will be zero, half of the time the number will be 2^31. Now, map that onto all the other bits. Half of the time, the number will be above the expected mean value, half of the time below. So if you choose all the bits in a 32-bit integer randomly, you end up with an integer with expected value 2^31 - 1, and with a uniform distribution in the range 0 to 2^32 - 1

Comment: You can trivially test it too. What is the probability of getting 0 if you choose 32 bits randomly? 1/2^32 . What is the probability of getting any specific 32 bit pattern (e.g. 00100010000100000101011110000000)? 1/2^32. So all numbers in the range are equally likely (provided that it's an integer, not a double that you're choosing this way).

Comment: No, `BitConverter.ToUInt64()` returns `ulong`, to perform the division with `MAX_RANGE` it has to be converted to `double`. Precision is lost even before the division.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71611/discussion-between-adam-brown-and-adriano-repetti).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'm a little worried about is the recreation of the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for every call to `Next` - creating 8 bytes. I think you'll get much better performance if you create more bytes, and only go back when the buffer is used up. So you could pre-create 2048 bytes, and then only go back to get new bytes every 256 calls, for instance.

I don't know about your specific use case, but most PRNG interfaces have a `NextDouble()` or something similar.

Overall, the distribution doesn't look like it's going to have any issues - as you said, the precision of a double is enough to exactly cover all integers.